# Can't change body background using CSS

Tags: css, background, document-body

I cant change my body background and background color with

For example:

```
body { background-color:#0c0; }
```

And

```
body { background-image:url(../images/bg/stone.png); }
```

Pleas help !

Comment: post your html please.

Comment: put your code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

**Possible reasons of not working:**

1. You haven't linked your stylesheet
2. Your image would not be in the same path.
3. Your image's extension would be different.
4. Your hash or hexadecimal color code is wrong.
5. Your path to image is wrong.

Comment: 1 check 2 check 3 check 4 check 5 check all are perfectly fine, i have fixed it though i created a div directly below my html body and added { background-color:#0c0; } and it worked ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle proving that it does work though the background of the body is a funny one as sometimes it calls it if you are calling it off the internet and sometimes it won't so make sure you have the image in a directory called images and the call it like this:

```
body {background: url('images/yourimage.jpg');}
```

and to add the color add your color like this:

```
body {background: red url('images/yourimage.jpg');}
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/xmj7C/

It uses this css:

```
body {
    background: red url('http://www.desktopas.com/files/2013/06/Images-1920x1200.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 500px 500px;
}
```

Make sure your file that your are calling it from is in the same directory as the one with the directory `images`